# Axios download file from returned url

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

I have returning data like:

```
data: "C:\laragon\www\test\public\exports\20200501030547-Products.xlsx"
message: "Products are successfully exported."
```

I want to start download `C:\laragon\www\test\public\exports\20200501030547-Products.xlsx` file automatically as it returns in success part.

## Code

```
axios.get( '/api/admin/products/export', {
    headers: {
        Authorization: localStorage.getItem('access_token')
    }
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res.data.data) // my file
    this.$notify({
        title: 'Hooray!',
        message: res.data.message,
        offset: 100,
        type: 'success'
    });
})
.catch(error => {
    var errors = error.response.data;
    let errorsHtml = '<ol>';
    $.each(errors.errors,function (k,v) {
        errorsHtml += '<li>'+ v + '</li>';
    });
    errorsHtml += '</ol>';

    this.$notify.error({
        title: 'Export Error',
        dangerouslyUseHTMLString: true,
        message: errorsHtml
    });
});
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: Please do mention; currently what problem you're facing?

Comment: @Mandy8055 as I said `I want to start download C:\laragon\www\test\public\exports\20200501030547-Products.xlsx file automatically as it returns in success part.`

Comment: @Mandy8055 when i get results back from back-end, start to download that file.

Comment: You can use [js-file-download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-file-download)

Comment: @Mandy8055 that i already have, that only works if you give data to it, if you give link (as i have) it write link url in excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

Solution was using `window.open('res.data.data', '_blank')` however if you use local data in chrome browser (as i am right now) it returns this error `Not allowed to load local resource:`

But I guess it shouldn't have any issue with production app in real server.

- hope it helps.